# running jar file from my class file in the IDE netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line, jar, classpath

I use a jar file called korat.jar. I executed with the command line:

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH korat.Korat --visualize --class test.Add --args 3
```

The classpath contains the path of the jar and also the Add.class file.

I want to execute this jar in my own program java in netbeans IDE. I think I would use:

```
String []s={test.Add.class.getName(),"--visualize","--class","test.Add","--args","3"};
```

Korat.main(s);

I get this exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "to execute the jar in my own program"? The jar contains some classes, if they are in your class path, you can instantiate the classes themselves and invoke some methods. In that case, you should use test.Add class. But it seems like the class is not in your classpath - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: it is a problem with classpath, now I added the Apache commons-cli library to my CLASSPATH
and I get this exception : java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 21 in method test.Add.__korat_get_a()I at offset 5